# How to execute code after missing a scheduled event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, redis, kue

I'm building a MEAN roll call app, where a professor opens the app and if there's a class to be taught, he's able to click on it and a lost of the enrolled students shows up. The professor can then mark each student present and click on a "Start class button", after which, any unchecked student and their supervisor gets notified of the student's absence.

However, my trouble is with marking a teacher absent when they do not show up which means they don't even open the app.

The app sets a class schedule, so it knows there should be a lecture on Mondays from 8am to 10am for example, but it has no calendar functionality.

The way I've currently implemented it in node is that when I create the weekly class schedule, I add a notification job to a redis queue for each day the lecture is expected to take place so that when the teacher actually shows up, the notification job is deleted. If not, a notification is sent to the supervisor after the lecture is scheduled to end.

I feel like creating many jobs to run for each lecture is a bit hacky and will not scale well.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assis,

1. presist the json when you create a weekly class
2. end of each class update the json and then check the current day is updated
3. if not send notification to supervisor

   - queue can get messy with lot of data later as you have to pass through the messages

Comment: Mattony, thanks for the answer, however there is one issue:

1. I already persist the JSON. I have a Schedule model and a Session model. For every lecture that is given, I save a new Session object with the date, time, teacher, schedule and other details.

2. This is where the problem is. Is a class is given, I'm fine, but if it's not, there I can't update anything as there is no trigger. The app was never oppened (only teachers use the app).

3. I agree as well

Comment: for step (2) would look at some kind scheduling where i can run the job as per weekly schedule and notifying the supervisor - node-rescue might solve that problem https://github.com/taskrabbit/node-resque

Comment: and we're back to Queues. I was using Kue but Resque is more salable as I only need to schedule a job for each session in a week, to repeat weekly.